# Can I check for multi-process apps on a device using adb?

Tags: applications, adb, processes

I have an Android device and I want to know either:

1. whether there are currently any apps running in multiple processes
2. whether there are any apps installed with the ability to run in multiple processes

Is either of these possible with `adb`?